# $\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{\frac nd}\phi(d)={}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, multiplicative-function

how to find $$\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{\frac nd}\phi(d)=?$$

Comment: What's the limit of the summation?

Comment: @Inceptio $d|n$

Comment: It was stated in a deleted answer that $(-1)^m$ is a multiplicative function. I think it is worth mentioning that it is not, in fact, multiplicative, so it does not suffice to check for prime powers.

Comment: In the title of this question, I extracted the question mark from the formula. The point is that an all-math-formula question makes it impossible to go to the question for those who have their MathJaX setting to "click to zoom".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We consider this sum for parity of $n$

If $n$ is odd, then $(-1)^{d}=-1$ for all $d\mid n$. (Because $d$ is also odd.) So
$$\sum_{d\mid n} (-1)^{n/d}\phi(d) = - \sum _{d\mid n} \phi(d)=-n$$

If $n$ is even, Let us take $n=2^r N$, where $N$ is an odd number and $r$ is a positive integer. Then this sum is represented in the following form:
$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{d\mid n} (-1)^{n/d}\phi(d) &= \sum_{i=0}^r \sum _{d\mid N} (-1)^{n/2^i d} \phi(2^i d) \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \sum_{d\mid N} (-1)^{n/2^i d} \phi(2^i d) + \sum_{d\mid N} (-1)^{N/d} \phi(2^r d)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \sum_{d\mid N} \phi(2^i)\phi(d) -  \sum_{d\mid N}\phi(2^r)\phi(d)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{r-1} \phi(2^i) \sum_{d\mid N} \phi(d) -  \sum_{d\mid N}\phi(2^r)\phi(d)\\
&=2^{r-1}N - 2^{r-1}N=0
\end{align*}
$$

So
$$\sum_{d\mid n} (-1)^{n/d}\phi(d) = \begin{cases}
-n & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: @anon It is my fatal mistake :( thanks to point out my mistake!

Comment: $(-1)^{\frac{N}{d}}=-1$ not $1$ since $d,N$ is odd

Answer (score 3):

If $n$ is odd then $(-1)^{n/d}=-1$ for each $d\mid n$. Otherwise given $n=2^vm$ with $v\ge1$ and $m$ odd,

$$\sum_{d\mid n}(-1)^{n/d}f(d)=\left[\sum_{d\mid 2^{v-1}m}f(d)\right]-\left[\sum_{d\mid m}f(2^vd)\right].$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: can you explain how the left side equal to the right one? I had struggeled too much wih no seccuss.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: For $n \ge 1$, $$\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)=n$$

Let $S=\{1,2,3,\dots n\}$. For every positive divisor $d$ of $n$, let $S_d=\{m \in S  |\gcd(m,n)=d\}$.

Then clearly, these sets $S_d$ are pairwise disjoint and their union is $S$.

Also $\gcd(m,n)=d \iff \gcd\left(\dfrac{m}{d},\dfrac{n}{d}\right)=1$. Hence the number of integers in the set $S_d$ is equal to the number of positive integers $\le\frac{n}{d}$ which are relatively prime to $\frac{n}{d}$ i.e equal to $\phi(\frac{n}{d})$.

Hence $n= \sum_{d|n} \phi\left(\dfrac{n}{d}\right)$. But as $d$ runs through all positive divisors of $n$, so does $\frac{n}{d}$. Hence

$$\sum_{d|n} \phi\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=\sum_{d|n} \phi(d)=n.$$

Comment: This is useful for the computation at hand, but I think insight as to how to handle the $(-1)^{n/d}$ factor in OPs problem is necessary for a good answer here. Also please use `\{` curly brackets `\}` for sets, as is standard - in number theory we often write $(a_1,\cdots,a_k)$ for the *gcd* of the numbers $a_i$ so it can easily be confused with this.

Comment: I will make sure of that. Thanks.